# Get number of items in a field that contain specific text

Tags: looker-studio

i have a field that lists all email address and i want to get the number of all email addresses with a certain domain, for example, "mydomain.com".

I can do this with a scorecard and a filter but I need to do this with a custom formula so i can also get the average.  My finial goal is to get the average of "mydomain.com" email addresses vs. the total.

I tried this

```
COUNT(CONTAINS_TEXT(profile.email, "@mydomain.com"))
```

But, of course, this does not work.

Maybe a COUNTIF?

Bottom lime, i need to figure out how to get the number of email addresses from a specific domain in to a variable so i can then do some math on it ;)

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you!

Comment: I solved it

CASE 
WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(profile.email, "@domain.com") THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END

Answer (score 0):

Everything I've read points to using a CASE statement, however I've not actually managed to get one to work.

Here's the documentation: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724

Comment: Yes, this is what I've found too....  and yes, i can't get it to work either :(